# Want to send jQuery value on next page after click on specific anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

I want to send the title value on next page means want to store this to completing a one process on completing the cart. Below is the code of jQuery I am using to get the value. It's working fine but when it goes to next page the value is not remain on hidden field, is there any way to store this value for particular time by using cookies etc so I can get this value on next page?

I need this value on cart page to show there as this is the store selection for user who want to buy items from this store.

Here are these store selection images http://toyourdoor24.com/pages/08002-local-stores
which I want to store for one user session to show this on cart page so we can know what is the user's store selection.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery(".span12 center a").click(function(event) {

          var titleStore = jQuery(this).attr('title');

          jQuery('.storefield').val(titleStore);

         });

         });
```

Comment: That's usually done by just adding a querystring to the anchors href ?

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use this value in query string, and then get that value from query string and use it.